# Cleaner method of doing IF

Tags: php

Basically, I'm performing an `if` statement on an array based on the returned value

```
<?php
if($array[1]>10000 AND $array[1]<50000){
        $selling = $array[1] - 250;
    }
    elseif($array[1]>50000 AND $array[1]<100000){
        $selling = $array[1] - 500;
    }
    else{
        $selling = $array[1] - 100;
    }
    $buying = $array[1] - 1000;

    if($array[1]>=10000){
        $buying = $buying-1000;
        if($array[1]>=20000){
            $buying = $buying-1000;
            if($array[1]>=30000){
                $buying = $buying-1000;
            }
                if($array[1]>=40000){
                    $buying = $buying-1000;
                }
                    if($array[1]>=50000){
                        $buying = $buying-750;
                    }
                        if($array[1]>=60000){
                            $buying = $buying-500;
                        }
                            if($array[1]>=70000){
                                $buying = $buying-500;
                            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

As you can see it's VERY messy, would anyone be able to point me in the correct direction for cleaning this up please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to get the feeling you are either not comfortable using maps as others have suggested here...so why not throw in a switch instead?

```
$volume = $array[1];

if($volume > 10000 && $volume < 50000){
    $selling = $volume - 250;
} else if($volume > 50000 && $volume < 100000){
    $selling = $volume - 500;
} else {
    $selling = $volume - 100;
}

$buying = $volume - 1000;

switch($volume){
    case 10000:
    case 20000:
    case 30000:
    case 40000:
        $buying = $buying - 1000; break;
    case 50000:
        $buying = $buying - 750; break;
    case 60000:
    case 70000:
        $buying = $buying - 500; break;
    default:
        $buying = $buying;
}
```

**REVISIT 01/26/2015**: Revisiting this to say that I would now rewrite this code as follows:

```
function bound_check($bounds, $bound_check, $default_value) {
    $return_data = NULL;
    foreach($bounds as $bound){
        if($bound_check >= $bound[0] && $bound_check <= $bound[1]){
            $return_data = $bound_check - $bound[2];
        }
    }
    return $return_data ?: $default_value;
}

$selling_bounds = [
    [10000, 50000, 250],
    [50000, 100000, 500],
];

$buying_bounds = [
    [10000, 40000, 1000],
    [50000, 50000, 750],
    [60000, 70000, 500]
]

$selling = bound_check($selling_bounds, $array[1], $volume - 100);
$buying = bound_check($selling_bounds, $array[1], $volume - 1000);
```

Comment: Your recent addition to your answer would probably be a good candidate for a second answer. Alternatively, since edits are not automatically part of the notification trigger to the OP, this comment itself will notify Curtis that this answer has changed. Note, on Code Review it is common, and acceptable, to post multiple answers to questions if the answers address things differently, or address different components of the original question.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @rolfl. I was not aware that multiple answers were acceptable here. Will keep that in mind with future edits

Answer (score 2):

First of all, replace `$array` with a descriptive name, and copy `$array[1]` into some other descriptive name.

Next, create a new array that describes those price ranges, in $10k increments, along with 1000, 750, 500, whatever. Give them a descriptive name, too, perhaps `$discount`. Now you can map a price range to a discount (or whatever business logic it is that your problem focuses on). Have a `for` loop scan through the map until it finds a matching price range, and apply the corresponding discount. For bonus points, wrap all that logic in a function, and have a unit test invoke the function with several different prices.